# Sync Pardot when Salesforce lead is updated

Tags: pardot

I have integrated my Salesforce sandbox with Pardot. When I update a prospect in Pardot, it gets updated in Salesforce but when I update the Salesforce Lead, it doesn't reflect back to Pardot. Am I missing any settings over here? I have made my Pardot as master here because otherwise when I update values in Pardot it does not reflect in salesforce but I still would like to see the Pardot prospect getting updated when Salesforce record is modified (a 2 way sync).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

you likely need to change the syncing option on the fields you're referring to.

In this image, the "Use the most recently updated record" is the bidirectional sync you are looking for.[image]